# Modify express request interface with internal class

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a class that standardizes API responses. It has a number of member methods, like `ResponseNotFound`. I currently use a middleware to attach an instance of this class to `req.apiResponse`. However, the interface `Express.Response` doesn't have the property `apiResponse`.

When the type is basic, such as `string` or `() => void` I have no problem modifying the Express types. But, in this case, I can't find a way to get the `ApiResponse` class into my `vendor.d.ts` file. If I import into my `.d.ts` file my declarations are no longer ambient. Is there a way to get the `ApiResponse` class typings into the `vendor.d.ts` file?

If not, what are my options?

Comment: While it looks similar, the accepted answer to that question doesn't solve my problem for two reasons. First, the Express typings are implemented differently. Second, the external import leads to my typings no longer being ambient and TypeScript rejects any alterations made.

Comment: Can you please provide sample code that you have tried so I can figure out why the approach from the other question isn't working?

Comment: I stand corrected, that solves my problem. Thank you.